# multiple word Predictive/autocomplete textarea?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, textarea

I'm lookin for a javascript plugin (for js/any framework)

I want to create a textarea that while I type will using a supplied data array, check for predictive matches to the current word im typing and try to suggest a solution.

All solutions I've found so far (for jquery) only match one word, then end...

I want to write like a sentence or paragraph but have autocomplete ability.

Mockup image attached.[alt text http://data.getafreelancer.com/project/212922/autocomplete-mockup.jpg](http://data.getafreelancer.com/project/212922/autocomplete-mockup.jpg)

Comment: Why closed? Useful question.

Comment: @Ryan This is a software recommendation question. Software recommendation questions should be posted on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have built my own at https://ayansome1.github.io/typeahead/ .For the code checkout https://github.com/ayansome1/typeahead

Answer (score 16):

There is [Wick](http://wick.sourceforge.net/wick_sample/) which does support textareas and multiple words.

Comment: That's goddamn awesome dude, no idea why you got downvoted

Comment: I have tried the site, and everytime, I enter some text, and after that text the word that matches, nothing happens. It looks for me that only the first word of the text area is checked for a match, not the word before the cursor. So possible no solution to the problem :-(

Comment: The examples on that site require a comma between email addresses, before it starts matching again. e.g. It won't match another address until you type ','

Comment: Wick is awesome and using it on a phone required arrow keys to be enabled to choose any option other than the first one. If tapping on an option worked, that would be a useful addition but that should be easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I just posted a [jquery plugin](http://www.amirharel.com/2011/03/07/implementing-autocomplete-jquery-plugin-for-textarea/) that does autocomplete in a textarea, I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Your URL is broken

Answer (score 1):

Me too: [See my answer and implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5611429/41540).

Answer (score 0):

Since Amir's plugin no longer provided a link to the source code, I extracted it from his examples and created a github project where I've added some enhancements to it. You can find it [here](https://github.com/LordZardeck/areacomplete):

Comment: Why is there jquery code being called before the $(document).ready function? Its giving me errors.